# Maximize window under Capybara with Chromedriver

Tags: capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Capybara to automate taking some screenshots.

I need the chrome browser to run maximized, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Based on https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities and http://grokbase.com/t/gg/webdriver/134fs2vm3v/window-maximize-using-selenium-webdriver-in-ruby  I thought the following should work:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args" => [ "start-maximized" ]})
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps})
end
```

But the browser size never changes.

Has anybody figured this one out?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue - https://gist.github.com/abotalov/7309217. Google Chrome is resized properly.

Answer (score 5):

Your solution works with me with just one fix:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args" => [ "--start-maximized" ]})
    $driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps})
```

You have given start-maximized where as it should be --start-maximized.

Using chrome driver 2.8 (http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.8/) on windows 7 platform.

Regards,
A.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maximize not on startup, but during the test, you can do:

```
page.windows[0].maximize
```

Answer (score 0):

This way is used java.Wish it can give you a light:
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

Answer (score 0):

Seem like we have to use `'goog:chromeOptions'` as a key instead of just `chromeOptions`, like this:

```rb
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
  'goog:chromeOptions' => {
    args: [
      'start-maximized',
    ]
  },
)

Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
  app,
  browser: :chrome,
  desired_capabilities: caps
)
```

Source: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

[image: Chromedriver Desired Capabilities]